# PDO SELECT with WHERE clause empty array

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to make an SELECT with PDO. I'm using the "username" column to  specify user info. When I use `"WHERE id = $user_id"` it returns the correct result, but when I use `"WHERE username = $username"` it returns an empty array.
Here is my code

```
USER MODEL FILE 

class user_model extends Models {
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

function e_mail_control($e_mail)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where(array('user_e_mail' => $e_mail));
    return $this->db->get('users', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

function username_control($username)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where(array('user_username' => $username));
    return $this->db->get('users', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}}
```

Comment: You have a typo in your function `$this->db->selectc('*');` you have an extra c after select

Comment: it's not. i'm writing them in diffrent lang. i changed them for here

Comment: I've never seen this syntax but my presumption is that you need to quote the username. I usually use the query function with parameterized values.

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

Comment: Is this Codeigniter? Please tag the framework you are using, because this isn't native PDO behavior or syntax.

Comment: @MahirKöle, you can activate the profiler and verify the select query, assuming that the username exists in database.

Comment: Some sample rows from the table may need to be posted, and also, the contextual code in which `username_control()` is called, to be able to debug the input value to `$username`.

Comment: i do not use CodeIgniter. I wrote my own classes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use single quote for `$username` :

```
WHERE username = '$username'
```

Comment: Nowhere in the posted code is any directly constructed SQL statement with a manually created `WHERE` clause. There's clearly a framework's query builder at play.

Comment: I'm sure you are the one who down-voted all these posts, so instead of doing so you can just give us a better answer or you can just F.O

Comment: Not, "all these", only your answer. I would provide a better answer if the OP supplies the necessary information requested in the comments above, and I know what the answer is when we have that information.